# In GIMP (DBP), how can I batch-resize photos to a certain width and keep aspect ratio?

Tags: gimp, gimpfu

I have been using GIMP to resize photos one by one, to say 800px-width while keeping aspect ratio. I downloaded the David Batch Processor plugin and everything looks fine, except it isn't able to resize to a predetermined width or height whilst keeping the aspect ratio.

- Relative: I can resize by % and keep aspect ratio, but the photos are of different sizes and orientation, so no one % works.
- Absolute: There isn't an option to keep aspect ratio, and no one height works for all photos.

Can someone please advise if there is a way to batch-resize photos of different original sizes using GIMP's dbp or there is some other plugin that can work?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that for whatever reason, that Dbp just doesn't have the function to keep the aspect ratio in absolute resizing, so either I write a script from scratch which is an overkill for my purpose or find another plugin for batch processing. I am now using one called Batch Image Manipulation. https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/